# How to call subroutine in a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to write a subroutine with name duplicate C that duplicates each element in a list of integer elements.

For example, a list before and after a call is deduced:
 1 5 8 6 → 1 1 5 5 8 8 6 6

The list is stored as a linked list where the nodes are given by:

```
struct nodeX{
int x; 
struct nodeX * next;
};
typedef struct nodeX node;
```

Comment: OK, and did you try anything and encounter any specific problem? SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I corrected it now to nodeX. Sorry

Comment: Seems fairly simple. Walk the list. For each node, malloc a new one and set new x to old x. Then re-link. New node next = old node next. And old node next  = new node.......Give that a try. If you can't get it to work, post your attempt.

Comment: where is your attempt?

Comment: dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62344321/how-can-i-have-a-function-duplicate-each-element-in-a-list-in-c